# Having trouble with Python os.rename() in my batch file renaming and moving script

Tags: python, file-io, for-loop, operating-system

Here is my batch file rename and move script so far

```
import os, re, shutil, random

mainpath = 'C:\\Users\\s3z\\Desktop\\pytest'
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]

for index, name in enumerate(dirs):
    subpath = name
    os.chdir(name)
    images = [i for i in os.listdir('.') if i[-4:] in ('.png', '.jpg', 'jpeg')]
    basename = re.sub(r'\W+', '', name[0:10])
    randid = str(random.uniform(0,1))[-4:] 
    for index, f in enumerate(images):
        path = os.path.join(mainpath, subpath)
        if f[-4:] == 'jpeg':
            ext = '.jpeg'
        else:
            ext = f[-4:]
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, basename + '_' + randid + '_' + str(index) + ext) 
        shutil.move(f, '..\..\COMMON')
    os.chdir(os.pardir)
```

I am having issues with the `os.rename()` function. When I run the script I get

```
  File "bulk_image_organizer.py", line 19
    shutil.move(f, '..\..\COMMON')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And when I take out line 19

`shutil.move(f, '..\..\COMMON')`

and try to run it again the error changes to

```
  File "bulk_image_organizer.py", line 19
    os.chdir(os.pardir)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But when I remove the `os.rename()` line the script works fine. Also when I run the `os.rename()` line in the Python interpretter in a for loop like in the following

```
>>> for index, f in enumerate(images):
...     os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, "new" + st
r(index) + ".jpg"))
...
```

It works fine. So what is going haywire in my script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `os.rename` or `os.chdir`. You're missing a closing parenthesis in the line before:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(path, f),
          os.path.join(path, basename + '_' + randid + '_' + str(index) + ext) 
#                                                                             ^
```